# Закрывать доступ к сайту, пока не прошёл авторизацию

Tags: php, html, laravel

обращаюсь с таким вопросом..
Есть небольшой сайт по подбору оборудования, грубо говоря там 2 страницы, клиент выбирает по критериям свой продукт, а после получает сформулированный документ. Страница написана на PHP Laravel и уже лежит на хостинге, подключена к БД. Вопрос состоит в том, можно ли закрыть доступ к сайту и выводить страницу с авторизацией/регистрацией, т.е. пока клиент не авторизуется он не получит доступ к странице подбора. Ответа на данный вопрос я не нашёл, может кто-то сталкивался, может подсказать, какие средства можно использовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно создать middleware по примеру так в файле routes/web.php

```
   Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () { 

    Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');
    Route::post('save-user', 'UserController@saveUser');
    Route::put('edit-user', 'UserController@editUser');
   });
```

и все маршрутизация добавить там, кроме Auth::routes();
после этого когда пользователь заходить например страницу /home если не авторизован его перенаправляет страницу  /login
а про middleware auth можно причитать там
https://appdividend.com/2022/01/23/laravel-middleware/

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и информацию, буду изучать!

Comment: Если будет вопрос напишите